# Solr dataimport with nested documents

Tags: solr, nested, dataimporthandler

From 4.5 version SOLR supports nested documents, but is there a DIH for this purposes?
I need to import parent and child documents from MySQL, but can't find any solution.

**UPD**
 thinkingisdifficult_hashtag.
The solution of my problem is a simple join, which is perfectly realized in SOLR

Comment: Instead of adding a answer to your question, you might consider to add answer to your question an accept is to show that it's resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of my problem is a simple join, which is perfectly realized in SOLR